# Issue with loading report

Tags: telerik-reporting

I have designed a report using Telerik Report Designer 2013 Q3 and added it in my project folder. Now i need to load it with available parameters for the report

For that i used the code as below

Private Sub DeserialiseXmlAndGenerateReport(strFilePath As String)
        Dim settings As New XmlReaderSettings()
        settings.IgnoreWhitespace = True
        Dim myReportBook As Telerik.Reporting.ReportBook = New Telerik.Reporting.ReportBook

```
    Using xmlReader As System.Xml.XmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(Server.MapPath(strFilePath), settings)
        Dim xmlSerializer As New Telerik.Reporting.XmlSerialization.ReportXmlSerializer()
        Dim reportWMS As Telerik.Reporting.Report = DirectCast(xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader), Telerik.Reporting.Report)

        With reportWMS
            .DocumentMapText = ""
            .ReportParameters("projectNo").Value = _projectNo
            .ReportParameters("dnHeaderNo").Value = _value
            .ReportParameters("transferType").Value = _TransferType
            ReportViewer1.DocumentMapVisible = False
            ReportViewer1.ShowDocumentMapButton = False
        End With

        myReportBook.Reports.Add(reportWMS)
    End Using

    Dim reportSource = New Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource
    reportSource.ReportDocument = myReportBook
    ReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportSource
    ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

End Sub
```

All the values for report parameters are supplied. But not getting any output. There is no exception fired. But a blank screen with a toolbar only gets loaded. Please help me

Comment: Is this ASP.NET? If so, did you look at the HTML output source - the report might be there but hidden due to style or other weirdness.

Comment: yes it is ASP.NET and the report is not hidden too

Comment: Can you maybe go back to basics. Load the XML direct rather thank via an XML reader (I am pretty sure you can do this by providing an absolute path to the XML report definition). Also try with a boring blank report with no params and just a hard code "REPORT TEST" label. That way you can test the most simple case and work back from there. I've definitely had situations where there is no exception thrown but no report shown and it always boiled back down to some assumption I'd made which wasn't true.